# Impossible to connect to Azure SQL database with ipv6 address due to recent forced update from v11 to v12

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In the early September Microsoft forced me to migrate from Azure SQL Database v11 to v12. My Internet Service Provider (ISP) assign me only ipv6 address and Azure doesn't allow connections through its firewall with this kind of address.

Until the past month I used the web browser to access the database management. Now with the upgraded version, Microsoft decided to close the access with web browser to the database management and obliges to connect with Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio.
However, Azure firewall accept only ipv4 address so it is impossible to connect with Visual Studio or Management Studio.

How to solve? Any ideas?

Comment: how are you trying to connect and what is the error ?>

Comment: I'm trying to connect with SQL Server Management Studio with authentication "SQL Server Authentication".

The error is (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53).

Comment: The client library will fall back to named pipes if you are unable to establish a connection via tcp. Are you sure you have the port open? Are you able to do the following without error:

telnet <servername> 1433

Answer (score 0):

Ipv6 is not supported by Azure SQL. It is not possible to connect to Azure SQL with Ipv6 only, as service doesn't listen on Ipv6