# Problems logging in to Azure from SSMS

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I had this problem previously (but didn't know the cause) and had to reformat my machine to eliminate the problem. Now I a pretty sure I know the cause:

I have both a wired and wireless internet connection. If I unplug my wired connection I cannot use SSMS to connect (forcibly closed by the remote host) to my Azure database (even though the wireless connection to the internet is fine). I can still connect using **sqlcmd** over the wireless connection.

By simply plugging/unplugging the Ethernet cable I have confirmed that this is the problem. I have checked my firewall rule for 1433 and it is supposed to be interface independent.

I've tried turning Firewall off completely and forcing TCP in the SQL connection properties.

Has anyone else found this to be a problem and found a solution? Is there a way to specifically tell SSMS to communicate over a specific network interface? Otherwise, I will have to reformat my machine again (and never use a wired Ethernet cable, since it worked fine before I ever plugged in an Ethernet cable) to eliminate this problem.

[image: With Wired Internet]
[image: Wired Internet Unplugged]
[image: 1433 Inbound Firewall Rule]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this doesn't seem to be a problem with SSMS at all. Although Windows responded that I had the latest Network Driver, I discovered that the manufacturer had a new driver and that seems to have solved the problem.

http://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/clean-install-killer-control-center/

Product Type    Killer(R) Wireless-AC 1550 Wireless Network Adapter (9260NGW) 160MHz
Product Type    Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller

My Hardware:
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Alienware
BIOS: 1.6.5 (type: UEFI)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you may be fighting (unbeknownst to you) network protocols.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/

in the above URL, find the section labeled "Network protocol codes"

"Network Library=dbmssocn"

The above network-library is the 'tcp' one..and is the most common (in 2019) version. (I started sql-server when named-pipes was the biggest player and learned the hard-way about network-protocols ! )

That is how you "force" a certain network protocol in a connection string.

You can also set this value in Sql Server Management Studio.

See here:

https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1893

Find the sentence

"2. If it does not work with default settings, go to Options > Connection Properties tab. And choose TCP/IP in the drop down menu for Network Protocol."

Try experimenting with that.

[image]

APPEND:

Your first two screen shots are really hard to read.  You have alot of blue space.  I'd suggest making your ssms window smaller, then taking the screen shot.

Are you using these credentials naming style?

> myazuresqlservername.database.windows.net,1433
>
> MyUserName@myazuresqlservername

Could it be this??

[Impossible to connect to Azure SQL database with ipv6 address due to recent forced update from v11 to v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591545/impossible-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-with-ipv6-address-due-to-recent-forc?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try that, but it didn't make a difference. TCP work fine if I have the wired interface enabled, but fails if the wired interface is disabled even though the wireless is enabled and working. Firewall rules seem to work fine on either interface using sqlcmd. I even tried turning off Firewall completely and get the same results. I edited my question to add that information.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  That stinks.  I'll give you one more helper hint.  Get this program, and this lets you just ping the machine/port without any middleman (sql-server is the middle man here).  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009  "PortQryUI - User Interface for the PortQry Command Line Port Scanner" Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I got a positive response from PortQryUI on both wired and wireless connections (TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): LISTENING portqry.exe -n gobo.database.windows.net -e 1433 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000000.) The only other information I can offer is that using ADO.net from VS2017 gives me the same error if wired Ethernet is disabled. Yes, I have tried all kinds of different login combinations. tcp:myazuresqlservername.database.windows.net,1433 is one I've been using. I am left with reformatting my machine again and never connecting to wired ethernet as the only solution.

Comment: One more poor man's hint/tip.  Try to connect using a Control Panel / Admin Tools/ ODBC / System DSN (or User DSN, either DSN).  Picking sql-server of course.  a DSN connection is a less intense middle-man than SSMS.  If that works (and you know portqueryUI works)..then you have high confidence SSMS is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. In both wired and wireless connections I get: "Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 10.00.17763

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
Connection established
Verifying option settings
Disconnecting from server

TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!"

Comment: if portquery works and system dsn works........you got some major voodoo going on.  #sorry  I'm out of ideas.  Can you try a different version of SSMS?  Even an "express" version?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have tried two different versions of SSMS. I got the same problems with both. I'm not sure why this isn't happening with everyone. This is literally a brand new Windows install with only SSMS running so there shouldn't be any conflicts unless it's something to do with the factory pre-installed Alienware (laptop) software... I will reformat without using wired ethernet and that should eliminate the problem. I hate not being able to fix it though...

Comment: check my most recent append on my answer.

Comment: Ipconfig shows I have both ipv6 and ipv4 and my error message is different, but I just noticed that when I re-enable wired Ethernet, both interfaces are active - UNTIL a connection is established with the Azure Database where the wireless status changes to "Not Connected". I don't know what normal behavior is for multiple interfaces? I would think they both should remain active?

Comment: That's outside my expertise.  But at least you might have found something.  good luck.